# grails spring security multiple custom (domain) classes

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have two types of users for my website: Seller and Buyer. Both of these domain classes are different (Seller has auctions and Buyer has bids). How can I create two domain classes using Spring security plugin?

1. Extend the User class to both Seller and Buyer - it will not work as I will have to register one class for spring security
2. Have the user object as an attribute in both Seller and Buyer. Will that work? Has anyone tried that before?

I could not find an example on internet. All I found was how to customise the plugin either by modifying User class or by extending it. If you can point me to some direction that will be good. I am new to Grails. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what *Seller* and *Buyer* mean.

If it's similar to Amazon.com; how they allow one account (aka. User) to have a seller profile and a customer (buyer) profile, then you can add Seller and Buyer properties to User.

```
class User { 
    Seller seller
    Buyer buyer
}
```

Then you would select the appropriate *profile* as needed.

```
springSecurityService.currentUser.seller
// or
springSecurityService.currentUser.buyer
```

If a User can be only either a Buyer or Seller, then a one-to-one association would be best, but it would require a common superclass for Buyer and Seller.

```
class User { 
    Static hasOne = [profile: UserProfile]
}

class UserProfile { }

class Seller extends UserProfile {
    User user
}

class Buyer extends UserProfile {
    User user
}
```

But with this approach you won't know which *type* of profile you've got. Because

```
springSecurityService.currentUser.profile
```

could return either type. If the type matters, then that's a warning sign that a one-to-one is not the right choice. An alternative might be a *user type* property in the User domain.

Comment: I'd also add that combined with one of these approaches (or something similar) you should consider creating a [custom UserDetailsService](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html). All that Spring Security wants is a username, password, enabled, locked, etc., and that data can come from anywhere. If the default domain classes aren't flexible enough then writing your own `UserDetailsService` to gather the data is a very common customization.

Comment: Thanks a lot Emmanuel & Burt for the advice. Will let you guys know if i face any issues.